# Using <canvas> to draw screen in .erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas

I'm using the following javascript code to help me draw an output screen in a .erb file which doesn't render properly. The canvas tag is unhelpful.

There is no output screen. The linking is proper and I am able to get output "hello" when I add a testing line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Programming++! Build Your Own Blocks</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="morphic.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="widgets.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="blocks.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="threads.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="objects.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="paint.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lists.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="byob.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="xml.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="store.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="locale.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cloud.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var world;
            window.onload = function () {
                world = new WorldMorph(document.getElementById('world'));
                world.worldCanvas.focus();
                new IDE_Morph().openIn(world);
         loop();
            };
                function loop() {
          requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                world.doOneCycle();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;">
         <canvas id="world" tabindex="1" style="position: absolute;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Check your browser console. Do you see any errors relating to files not being found? If so, make sure that all the files you include in this page are accessible by rails

Comment: What does this have to do with ERB or ruby on rails? All I see is a static HTML file.